# How to use Java delimiter patterns?

Tags: java, regex, string, delimiter

I'm trying to figure out how to use delimiter patterns in Java. I have tried googling and searching stack overflow but I can't find anything that answers my questions. How do you set patterns for useDelimiter? I'm trying to set a delimiter that separates text once it finds `<` and delimits to `>`. So in a string of text `"this is <my> text"` it will separate `"this is "`, `"<my>"`, `"text"`. I tried:

```
src.useDelimiter("<->");
```

and many other combinations. I see people using `[]` and `^`, but I don't know what this means. Is there some guide for making these patterns?

Comment: Do you mean [`regular expressions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Comment: I'm trying to use \p{Punct} but I am getting an error "Invalid Escape Sequence" even though I have import java.util.regex.Pattern

Comment: @PM77-1 Three? Shouldn't it be two?

Comment: @Tom : Yep. You are right. Just two (`\\\`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
src.useDelimiter(" (?=<)|(?<=>) ")
```

Pattern `A(?=B)` matches A followed by B, but matches only A.

Pattern `(?<=A)B` matches A followd by B, but matches only B.

See
**Special constructs (named-capturing and non-capturing)**
in
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: It was downvoted because @mgtemp specifically asked for guidance making regexs. A code-only post does nothing to help him.